# Set up TCP/IP connection over the internet issue

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient

Hi, 
I'm trying to connect my chat client to my server, but I keep getting an error.  I have chat server which is running in a machine which is published in internet and it has fixed IP address and it is running on port 5001.  When my chat client tries to connect to that server then I am get the error. The line which is raising error as follows

```
    ipAddr = IPAddress.Parse(txtIp.Text);
    // Start a new TCP connections to the chat server
    tcpServer = new TcpClient();
    tcpServer.Connect(ipAddr, 5001);
```

When I run both my chat client & server in my local machine with local machine IP, it works. 
Please tell me what I need to changes in code as a result my chat server & client both can communicate over the internet. Thanks

Comment: You haven't defined the error you are getting. What is it? Aside that, your code is confusing. You name the TCP Client object tcpServer. I would rename this to client: client = new TcpClient(); Please post the error message you get and I will edit my post accordingly.

Comment: it's maybe a network issue, instead of a code issue. Do you have any router / firewall ?

Comment: The actual error message would help.

Comment: how about connect with hostname? `tcpClient.Connect ("hostname", 5001);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed IP might not be enough if it goes first through some network of computers.
You might need to Forward Port if it is simple network, or if it is more complicated probably it has own direct line but have closed Ports so you have to open them through Firewall within system as well within possible hardware that can filter traffic.

It probably not the code issue at all.

As well when you create server socket, try to Bind it to IPAddress.Any, because if you bind it to specific device it might be source of problem as well.

Comment: Because based on his words, he used client and server code running on localhost, and it worked, so it means there is no problem with code it self, but problem might be based on networking issues I described in this answer.

Comment: our come has taken one staging server where we often host asp.net site for testing before upload to main server. the staging server has fixed ip. after hosting our page there we can access page through that fixed ip like 192.168.11.12/home.aspx. this ip is just as example not real one. so i thought when we have fixed ip then we can run chat server there and client app can run on my machine and could connect chat server by that ip. when we run chat client and try to connect to server by that ip then we get error. later i will post that error.

Comment: i am not very good in networking. there is no firewall i think on that machine. so please tell step by step that how to enable port forwarding on that staging server.any tool can help me to start port forward on that machine.i will be happy if some one guide me in detail.thanks